# issue in swift trying to dispatch and subscribe events

Tags: ios, swift, events

I am new to swift.
I am trying to build an app and I have a question about dispatching and subscribing events in swift.
Basically I have a custom UIView that create a couple of custom knobs and switches
The class is working fine.
What I need now is that when I rotate one of the knob (or I push the button), an event is dispatched. I need to listen for this event in the main ViewController.
I need to send possibly a class or a struct as I need to send multiple values like: my control type, my control name, value, and some custom property.
I have tried the notification center that looks like is one of available options but apparently I can just send a dictionary? Can you please provide some example of an event dispatch and subscription using any viable technique? Notification Center, protocols, anything that can solve my issue

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Post you code; and somebody can advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about how your architecture looks, but what you describe sounds like a job for delegates (the delegate pattern on iOS). And you are right - with notification you can only send information in the userInfo dictionary.